# Modify Array Structure

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to make my array stay in this structure:

```
array
(
  0 => array (
       "url"=> "http://localhost/theme/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/img2.png"
       "caption"=> "title text test"
      )
)
```

Currently my array looks like this:

```
array
( 
  "url" => "http://localhost/theme/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/065.jpg" 
  "caption" =>  "test other capition" 
)
```

I tried to join the two array

```
 $first = array();
 $NewArray = array($first, $urlsCaptions);
```

Output:

```
array( 
    0 => array(),
    1 => array(
     "url" => "http://localhost/theme/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/065.jpg" 
     "caption" => "test other capition"
     )
 )
```

How do I create the array correctly, with the structure identical to the first array of my question?

Comment: Try this `$NewArray = array($urlsCaptions);`

Comment: @SahilGulati Great, that worked.

Comment: welcome friend... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$arr = array ($originalArray);
```